# Apache NiFi - Process content of a CSV S3Object

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I am trying to process a CSV stored in a S3 Bucket with Apache NiFi.

For this aim I am using the following flow:

[image]

The thing is that I need to replace some text of the csv file, but what I get as a output of FetchS3Object is a file, not a text.

[image]

How can I access to the text of the S3Object?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that the FlowFile is not a textobject?  In your screen shot, you are viewing it as hex but if you view it as text won't it be correct?

Comment: Because when I try to see the content of the output of FetchS3Object it doesn't appear, and if I download I get the original file instead (csv with original name)of the raw data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way to fix the problem.

Using SplitText processor after FetchS3Object is possible to split line by line (count = 1) and process each line after that processor.

[image]

[image]